# Bigquery error, "parenthesized expression cannot be parsed"

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hello i have the next code and when i run it inside Bigquery is giving me the "correct" answer but when i put it into a sh script and execute the script inside google shell vm gives me the next error. Any thoughts?

I suppose the error lies in the need to multiply case/when statements results inside another case/when statement..

This is an example of what my code looks like:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN (
           (CASE WHEN TABLE1.COL1 = 'X' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) *
       (CASE WHEN TABLE2.COL2 = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) *
       (CASE WHEN (SELECT 0 
                       FROM TABLE3
                       WHERE TABLE3.ID = TABLE2.ID) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)) = 1
    THEN (SELECT '111111') ELSE NULL END
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2
ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
FULL JOIN (SELECT COL1,'TRUE' FROM TABLE4) AS XX
ON XX.COL1 = TABLE1.COL1 AND XX.COL1 IS NULL
WHERE
  TABLE1.COL3 = 'YY'
```

I cant provide the expected result but the result of that query gives me the next error: Parenthesized expression cannot be parsed as an
expression, struct constructor, or subquery at...

Comment: Are you using Legacy or standard sql

Comment: standard SQL, sorry not to mention it

Answer (score 1):

I'll post debugging tips as an answer since I think you'll probably find the problem this way. From a command-line prompt, list recent jobs:

```
bq ls -j --all
```

The failed query job will probably be at the top. Copy the job ID and use it with the next command:

```
bq --prettyformat=json show -j YOUR_JOB_ID
```

This will print out the complete job configuration as well as the error message. What I suspect you'll see is that the query is garbled; the quotes or some other character may have caused unexpected behavior when interpreted by the shell. When executing queries from the command-line, it's a good idea to put the contents in a file, then pipe it as input to the bq tool, e.g.

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false < query.sql
```

This prevents the shell from intercepting any part of the query as a command.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is not very useful, as it gives me the same explanation: The expression in parentheses cannot be interpreted as an expression, constructor of structures or subconsultation in....

Comment: The important part is finding the query that BigQuery received, not the error message...Does the query look correct in the output of `bq show`?

Comment: No it doesn't.. I dont know why but replace every * in the case statement with the name of a txt file.. I don't know what the hell is doing.. Looks like something like this: SELECT CASE WHEN ( ( CASE WHEN .... THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) PPV name_of_same_file.txt (CASE WHEN...) PPV name_of_some_file_txt (....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Elliott Brossard, i resolved the problem with literally no change in the code hah. So what i did was rewrite the bq query sentence like: bq query --destination_table=.. --use_legacy_sql=false --replace 'QUERY' instead of assign the query to a variable and then execute it with an echo | bq query sentence..

Thanks